# Need help with stuck bitcoins

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions, transaction-fees

I have an issue that's probably happened lots of people already, so I'm really sorry for asking the same question. My transaction is stuck since 28.12.2017 already. I've accidentally paid not enough fee to ever get it confirmed. I wanted to pay 0.0001BTC but I've paid a total fee of 0.00001BTC. So not even a transaction accelerator can help me out with this problem anymore. My question is now, what can I do to get my bitcoins back or even get it ever confiormed?

Best regards,

Sazer

Comment: What wallet did you sent them to and are you at the receiving adress aswell?

Comment: Yeah, I am also the receiving adress. I sent it to a Shop wallet.

Comment: What Accelerator did you try and what wallet did you send it from?

Comment: I've used the accelerator from viabtc and instantbt. I'm using the Bitcoin Core Wallet for all my transactions.

Answer (score 0):

try use `abandontransaction "Your transaction ID here"` and then restart it with -rescan flag

and then add your transaction fees higher (NOTE: ONLY WORKS IF TRANSACTION IS NOT IN THE BLOCKCHAIN)